# Passing variable between PHP functions

Tags: php

I have the following function:

```
class TariffFareController {

public static function checkRunin($fieldPickup) {

    $runInThreshold = 5;
    $fieldDestination = 6;

    if ($fieldPickup > $runInThreshold && $fieldDestination > $runInThreshold)

    {

        if ($fieldPickup > $fieldDestination)

        {

            $distance = $fieldPickup - $runInThreshold;

        } else {

            $distance = $fieldDestination - $runInThreshold;

        }


       }
}
```

I want to pass `$distance` to this function:-

```
private static function getFare($int_terminate) {

    //CODE
    //eg// if($distance > 5) {

        //do something

    }

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Call the function and pass it as a parameter

Comment: What do you mean by you want to "pass $distance"? Will you be calling getFare from within checkRunin?

Comment: I want to use $distance in the getFare function, so I can do something like if($distance > 5) { //DO SOMETHING }

Comment: @nsilva can you not declare $distance as a static variable and set it and access it as so from each of your methods?

Comment: Ahh that's easy... Are you accessing these via any instance or static methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say its does not work ... it basically because `$diffrent` was not properly declared so you are having `scope` issues

**My Assumption**

- Both `checkRunin` and `getFare` are method of the same class `TariffFareController`
- `$int_terminate` is different from `$distance`

**From your class**

- `$distance` not declared as `static`
- `getFare` is trying to access `$distance` that has not been declared

**Simple Solution**

```
class TariffFareController {
    private static $distance = 0;

    public static function checkRunin($fieldPickup) {
        $runInThreshold = 5;
        $fieldDestination = 6;
        if ($fieldPickup > $runInThreshold && $fieldDestination > $runInThreshold) {
            if ($fieldPickup > $fieldDestination) {
                self::$distance = $fieldPickup - $runInThreshold;
            } else {
                self::$distance = $fieldDestination - $runInThreshold;
            }
        }
        printf("self:\$distance = %d ; // Called %s :\n", self::$distance, __METHOD__);
    }

    public static function getFare($int_terminate) {
        printf("self:\$distance = %d ; // Called %s :\n", self::$distance, __METHOD__);
    }
}

TariffFareController::checkRunin(10);
TariffFareController::getFare(2);
```

**Output**

```
self:$distance = 5 ; // Called TariffFareController::checkRunin :
self:$distance = 5 ; // Called TariffFareController::getFare :
```

Answer (score 5):

`return` the value from the first function:

```
public static function checkRunin($fieldPickup) {
    $runInThreshold = 5;
    $fieldDestination = 6;

    if ($fieldPickup > $runInThreshold && $fieldDestination > $runInThreshold)
    {
        if ($fieldPickup > $fieldDestination)
        {
            $distance = $fieldPickup - $runInThreshold;
        } else {
            $distance = $fieldDestination - $runInThreshold;
        }
    }
    return $distance;
}

// Get $distance from checkRunin()
$distance = $obj->checkRunin($fieldPickup);
// Pass $distance as a parameter
$obj->getFare($distance);
```

Comment: Return the variable `$distance` in the first function only if it makes sense for that function to do that. `checkRunin` doesn't seems so obvious it will return some kind of a distance to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
class TariffFareController {

public static $distance = 0;
public static function checkRunin($fieldPickup) {

$runInThreshold = 5;
$fieldDestination = 6;

if ($fieldPickup > $runInThreshold && $fieldDestination > $runInThreshold)

{

    if ($fieldPickup > $fieldDestination)

    {

        self::$distance = $fieldPickup - $runInThreshold;

    } else {

        self::$distance = $fieldDestination - $runInThreshold;

    }


   }
}
```

then

```
private static function getFare($int_terminate) {

//CODE
//eg// if(self::$distance > 5) {

    //do something

}

}
```

Comment: That's great thank you. However, in some of the other functions I now have an error because I am returning the fare as follows `return self::getFare(0);` and so it is expecting the parameter $fieldPickup. What would I have to change this to? - do apologise, i'm fairly new to PHP

Comment: sorry could you please elaborate on the problem, I'm not sure I follow. you have two static methods checkRunin($fieldPickup), and getFare($int_terminate) what in getFare is expecting $fieldPickup?

Comment: Also as a matter of note, i'm not sure if creating all these methods and parameters as static is the best way of trying to do what it seems like you are trying to do. Although I understand that we dont get the whole scope of the problem and solution on stackoverflow. Thanks

Comment: sorry ignore the bit above. I've done as you have said, if I `echo(self::$runindistance)` I get the value within the checkRunin function, however, if I `echo(self::$runindistance)` within the getFare function, the variable is null. Any ideaS?

Comment: $runindistance is declared where and how? have you substituted distance for $runindistance?

Comment: sorry, yes I have substituted $distance for $runindistance as I already have a variable called $distance within the getFare function

Comment: if I change `public static $runindistance = 0;` to 10, and echo(self::$runindistance) within the getFare function it is returning 10, it seems as if `self::$runindistance = $fieldPickup - $runInThreshold;` is not update the static variable somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

`public static function checkRunin($fieldPickup) {`
`$runInThreshold = 5;`
       `$fieldDestination = 6;`

```
if ($fieldPickup > $runInThreshold && $fieldDestination > $runInThreshold)
{
    if ($fieldPickup > $fieldDestination)
    {
        $distance = $fieldPickup - $runInThreshold;
    } else {
        $distance = $fieldDestination - $runInThreshold;
    }
}
return $distance;
```

`}`

`// Get $distance from checkRunin()`
`$distance = $obj::checkRunin($fieldPickup);`
`// Pass $distance as a parameter`
`$obj::getFare($distance);`

that is the answer from @John Conde
just don't forget the static scope use ::

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why the answer above didnt work for you.  But try this idea
    class someThing {      protected $distance;      protected function initDistance() {      $this->distance = 5;  }      protected function useDistance(){      if($this->distance < 5) {      //do anything  }  }  $obj = new someThing();  $obj->initDistance();  $obj->useDistance();

Answer (score -1):

Would it not be possible to use sessions as follows:-

```
session_start();

public static function checkRunin($fieldPickup) {

    $runInThreshold = 5;
    $fieldDestination = 6;
    $_SESSION['runin_distance'] = 0;

    if ($fieldPickup > $runInThreshold && $fieldDestination > $runInThreshold) {

        if ($fieldPickup > $fieldDestination) {

            $_SESSION['runin_distance'] = $fieldPickup - $runInThreshold;


        } else {

            $_SESSION['runin_distance'] = $fieldDestination - $runInThreshold;

        }

    }

}
```

and then...

```
private static function getFare($int_terminate) {

    if($_SESSION['runin_distance'] > 5) {

    //do something

    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

create distance as a global variable, set it when in checkRunIn, then access it when you need it in getFare